# Generating a proper ssh keypair on Lenny for Github

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-10.04, debian-lenny, github

I have a codebase hosted in GitHub.

I have 2 ubuntu machines (both on 10.04) that I develop on. On these machines I had no trouble generating my keypairs as per GitHub's instructions. Using the command `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "emailaddress"`

My server runs Debian Lenny.

Now I was planning to do a clone/pull from my server to keep that updated. Since that always worked fine for me when using SVN I figured I could do the same with git.

When trying to generate an ssh keypair however, I was presented with the problem that it insists on making an ssh2 keypair. Additionally, the -C command is invalid as well.

Also, running `ssh-key --help` yields a different output on my server than Ubuntu.

So, I'm kind of lost here. There are different applications named ssh-keygen at play here?

Disclaimer: I might be forgetting to check some really basic stuff but together with a friend we're trying to manage the hurdles we face on the fly. We're neither really hardcore linux people :)

Answer (score 2):

-C is pretty useless.. it just adds a comment just use the command without it. Then add the new key to your github account

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Comment: Well, the problem is that that doesn't work. The command works, git just doesnt approve of the result.

This is the result output:

Private key saved to /home/reinier/.ssh2/id_rsa_1024_a
Public key saved to /home/reinier/.ssh2/id_rsa_1024_a.pub

I dont get why it does the .ssh2 thing, which is probably the cause of my issue. Thank you.

Comment: Then you pasted it into your account wrong because that works for me and I'm an active member of github

Answer (score 0):

All keys generated by SSH, Debian or Ubuntu, are SSH2 keys.  Also, Debian writes data into `~/.ssh` by default, so I'd look into why your machine is going something different -- I'd expect there's some oddity in your SSH config (either global or local) that's causing issues -- possibly both your key location and login failure issues.